# Injecting the same instance with StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scope, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have an interface IConnection, implemented by TcpConnection. In addition, two classes accept IConnection as a parameter, and I would like to use the same instance of TcpConnection for that.

The problem is it doesn't seem to work. With every method I tried, TcpConnection was created more than once. Here is the *Registry* subclass I'm using:

```
public class InstanceRegistry : Registry
{
    public InstanceRegistry()
    {
        var connection = 
            For<IConnection>.Add<TcpConnection>.
            Named("Connection"); // ...and additional configuration

        For<IFoo>.Add<Foo>.
            // Ctor<IConnection>.Is(connection);  // Did not work
            Ctor<IConnection>.Is( i => i.GetInstance<IConnection>("Connection") );                

        For<IBar>.Add<Bar>.
            // Ctor<IConnection>.Is(connection);  // Did not work
            Ctor<IConnection>.Is( i => i.GetInstance<IConnection>("Connection") );
    }
}
```

I even tried declaring IConnection as Singleton ("For<>().Singleton()"), but that didn't help either. I'm using StructureMap 2.6.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
For<IConnection>().Singleton().Add<TcpConnection>().Named("Connection");
For<IFoo>().Add<Foo>().Ctor<IConnection>().Is(i=>i.GetInstance<IConnection>("Connection"));
For<IBar>().Add<Bar>().Ctor<IConnection>().Is(i=>i.GetInstance<IConnection>("Connection"));
```

When I use the code above I have the same instance of connection in Foo and Bar. I have also tired with several named connections. Foo and Bar still get the connection their suppose to.

Comment: See the end of my post, I've already tried using Singleton. I can't use "Use<>()" in my case, because other connections are needed for other objects.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to post the solution that worked for me (basically the same, just replace Singleton with HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped), but your solution works as well.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in *similar* case (but I'm really just a StructureMap beginner, so I'm looking forward for any advices) is used the

`For<>().Use(x => SomeFactoryMethod())`

```
For<IInterface>().Use(x => CreateInstance());

private IInterface CreateInstance()
{
     // get some dependancy
     // inject it to both arguments down here
     return new ConcreteInstance(...);
}
```

Comment: This method is referred to as "Using an Externally Constructed Object" (http://structuremap.net/structuremap/InstanceExpression.htm#section12). But that means that if TcpConnection has dependencies, I would have to resolve them manually...

Comment: Yes, I guess so, but you still have autowire down the chain for those dependancies when you call GetInstance<> to manually resolve